# Pass values present in S3 bucket to AWS Lambda environment variables

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda function created which has 3 Environment variables defined in it. The values of these variables are stored in external file in S3 Bucket. 
How can i get the values for variables present in file & trigger the lambda function ? 
Is it required for me to create another lambda for this activity so that i have 2 lambda functions overall ?

Comment: You need to edit your question to explain in much greater detail what exactly you are looking for. You are getting answers that don't fit your scenario because so far your scenario doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can trigger a lambda on the S3 put event. please find a example below. [s3 upload trigger lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)
2. You can use cloudformation or terraform to pass in environment variables to your lambda function [Template for lambda cloudformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-lambda.html)
   Just to make things clear we
3. can use terraform to read a body of text/* or application/json file stored in s3 (as long as it is human readable).
4. Once you read the value you can pass that to the lambda you want.

   variable "environment" {
     default = "staging"
   }

   data "aws_s3_bucket_object" "release_id" {
     bucket = "my-s3-bucket"
     key    = "myapp/{var.environment}/current"
   }

   output "release_id" {
     value = "${data.aws_s3_bucket_object.release_id.body}"
   }
    resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
     s3_bucket         = "${data.aws_s3_bucket_object.lambda.bucket}"
     s3_key            = "${data.aws_s3_bucket_object.lambda.key}"
     s3_object_version = "${data.aws_s3_bucket_object.lambda.version_id}"
     function_name     = "lambda_function_name"
     role              = "${aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn}" # (not shown)
     handler           = "exports.test"

   lambda_environment_variables_map = {
       LOG_LEVEL = "${var.lambda_log_level}"
       ENV_NAME = "${var.environment}"
       S3_VALUE = "${data.aws_s3_bucket_object.release_id.body}"
     }
   }
5. please referance this [example](https://www.rover.com/blog/engineering/post/reading-external-configuration-terraform-using-s3-objects/)

Comment: Thanks for the above article . I have different scenario explained above can you provide inputs to this

Comment: @HrishikeshG i have updated the reply with the code you need using terraform.
hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to attach an s3 event notification configuration file which defines how lambda functions are invoked with s3 bucket events. Amazon S3 notification feature enables you to receive notifications when certain events happen in your bucket. See [Configuring Amazon S3 Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html?shortFooter=true#notification-how-to-overview)

Comment: In my case there will not be multiple puts into file in S3 its going to be updated once in a while , this file will hold many key value pairs that will be the input for the Environment variables.

Comment: Ex: I will have 3 variables a , b , c for every lambda trigger these values will change which will be stored in S3 . Var a will have 3 values , b will have 3 values & c will have 3 values every time lambda triggers one after the other values has to be passed to variables a , b , c in Lambda

Comment: i suggest you work with your environment from AWS lambda SDK which you can easily require in your script/file. see invoking lambda functions https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-functions.html